# Delete a leaf node in binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

i am trying to delete a `leaf node` from **binary search** tree, and it is not working for me, i debugged the code and, i can't find the issue. I can see flow is going correct, call reaches to `leaf node` address, and then calls `free`. But after that when i execute `pre-order` traversal i see the value is still there.

Binary tree i created(Its a simple one) -:

```
                           10
                         /    \
                        6      14
```

`Leaf Node` value to be deleted = `14`;

Before deletion `Pre - order` traversal result = `10->6->14`. This is printed on my console.

Code to delete `leaf node` -:

```
// Delete a leaf node

void deleteNode(struct Nodes * root,int value){

    // Check if root is null

    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // If no left and right node present, it's a leaf node. Perform delete.

    while (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {

        // Check if value at leaf node is same as value to be deleted. If yes, go inside (if).

        if (root->info == value) {
            printf("Delete the leaf node \n");

            printf("delete node address is \n %p",root);

            // free the root (which is currently a leaf node)
            free(root);
            return;
        }
    }

    // keep checking if value to be deleted is on right or left, till a value is found.

    if (root->info < value) {
        // Ccheck on right
        deleteNode(root->right,value);
    }else{
        // check on left
        deleteNode(root->left,value);
    }

}
```

I don't get any `errors`, so i am not able to guess **root cause**.

After deletion `Pre - order` traversal result = `10->6->14`. Can anyone help me out? I know i am doing very silly mistake, or my concept is still not crystal clear.Thanks.

> Please let me know if any other information is required.

Image of output-: You can see I am on correct value, and the address for same.

[image]

Comment: Somehow, maybe you need to set the `free()`-d node to `NULL`, otherewise, you'll be reading invalid memory.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried root=NULL; but same result. How can I check for invalid memory?

Comment: C uses pass by value....

Comment: @SouravGhosh oh I see. That means i still have a copy of value and not reference? How can I get one here?Any link to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` means pretty much "I swear I will not use the memory any more, it may be free'd or reallocated arbitrarily".

You are violating that promise. After freeing the memory, you must also forget all references on that address. The parent node still remembers the address where the node used to be, and by chance the memory has not been recycled yet.

You have a typical "use after free" error. If you had allocated another node in between, before traversing again, you would have noticed a memory corruption.

You could add one more parameter to your function which points to the pointer in the parent object. That way you can modify the parent.

Or store a reference back to the parent in the node.

Either works.

Comment: I guess I got your point, and which is absolutely correct here.Great!! let me check with this idea, and I will surely accept the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks sir that was it.:)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to pass the pointer to the parent in the recursive call. Something like this:

```
void deleteNode(struct Nodes *root, struct Nodes *parent, int value){

    // Check if root is null

    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if ((root->info == value) && (root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL)) {
        if (parent->left->info == value) {free(parent->left); parent->left = NULL;}
        else {free(parent->right); parent->right = NULL;}
    }
    else if (root->info < value) {
        // check on right
        deleteNode(root->right,root, value);
    }else{
        // check on left
        deleteNode(root->left,root, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up with. +1